# class not working properly

Tags: c++, class

Im still trying to learn classes, but I created this and I seem to be getting some weird number like a memory number or some thing and i cant figure out whats wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class JoesClass {
public:
    int setAge(int age) {       
        return age;
    }

    void displayAge() {
        cout << "your age is " << age << endl;  
    }
private:
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    JoesClass newobject;
    newobject.setAge(40);
    newobject.displayAge();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
int setAge(int age) {
    return age;
}
```

doesn't set the age. It just returns the value you give it, without updating the class member. You want something more like:

```
void setAge(int age) {
    this->age = age;
}
```

You might want to change the argument name, so it doesn't hide the class member:

```
void setAge(int new_age) {
    age = new_age;
}
```

<sub>You should also get out of the habit of putting `using namespace std;` in the global namespace, and instead qualify standard library names like `std::cout`. While the using directive saves a bit of clutter, it can cause problems when you declare something with the same name as something in the library.</sub>

Comment: OK, Thanks, I see it now I just changes the variable in the function to X.

Comment: Why do you suggest using `age = new_age;` as opposed to `this->age = age;`? I find latter easier to read since it's more explicit.

Comment: Change the name to something more descriptive than `X`. I'd use what Mike has suggested if you are not using `this->age = age;`

Comment: @user2079303: I suggest both, according to taste. Some people object to hiding members; others (including myself, at least for very simple functions like this) don't. Personally, I prefer the first version as you do, which is why I put it first.

Answer (score 3):

You are just returning the `age` that the caller passes in. You need to set the object's `age` member variable to that value.

```
void setAge(int age)
{
  this->age = age;
}
```

`this` is used to prevent variable hiding (your member variable is named "age" as well as the parameter name "age"). Which "age" are you referring to? That is where `this` can be used to explicitly state that "I want to use this object's `age` variable".

You may also want to wrap your `displayAge` method with a check for a valid age with something like the following:

```
void displayAge()
{
  if (age != 0)
  {
    std::cout << "your age is " << age << std::endl;
  }
}
```

and give your `age` variable a default value in the constructor:

```
JoesClass()
{
  this->age = 0;  // Initial value is considered not a valid age
}
```

Now when you create your class you'll have an initial value for age.

Comment: Return type should be `void`

Comment: Yes, it should be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

But, you're not *setting* the `age` variable in the `setAge` function. That means that the `age` member variable is uninitialized, and will contain a seemingly random value. Using uninitialized values leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Any tips on how to fix that?